# Php script for Export Amazon product

Tags: php, excel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to display Amazon product on my php website. I already created Amazon api key,Amazon Secret key and also want to export them in excel file.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any questions?

Comment: @Oswald how can i do this i need php script

Comment: Use one of the many libraries available to create Excel files from within PHP scripts, such as my own [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download amazon product web service from github.

following is the link for the same:-

https://github.com/Exeu/Amazon-ECS-PHP-Library